# JWT Configuration in Java 8 now doesn't work anymore in Java 17 because WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

Im using JWt for my API using Springboot with Java 8 (or 1.8 - in build gradle - im new). Now it's update to Java 17 and i can't use Class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter because is deprecated. This is my old Config, can someone help me out!

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

   
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/member/**").hasAnyAuthority("MEMBER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**JwtRequestFilter**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private IJwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Request Token Header it not begin with 'Bearer' String!");
        }

        
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

I can totally fix the build gradle
from

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.17'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

but i want to learn something new.

I would appreciate any kind of help that would be most welcome!
Thanks you for reading!